# Prove this is a Connected Component

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $Y$ = $ \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}\  |\  xy = 0\ \ \cap\  (x,y) \neq (0,0)\  \}$

Consider $U_+ = \{\ (x,0) \in \mathbb{R^2}\ |\ x>0\ \}$

I'm trying to show that $U_+$ is a Component of $Y$

My definition of a Component is non empty subset which is Simultaneously Open, Closed and Connected.

I've seen a different answer which trys to prove it's maximal directly but I'm wondering how to do it from this definition.

Thoughts?

Comment: Prove that it's open, then prove that it's closed, then prove that it's connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$U_{+}$ is open:** $U_{+} = Y \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x > 0\}$.

**$U_{+}$ is closed:** $U_{+} = Y \cap \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \geq 0\}$.

**$U_{+}$ is connected:** The function $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow U_{+}$ which sends $x$ to $(x,0)$ is clearly continuous and surjective. That means $U_{+}$ is the image of a connected space under a continuous function, and therefore connected. Of course, you need to know that $(0,\infty)$ is connected first.

Comment: Damn, that was too obvious for me to miss. Thanks !